# Powershell: Auto press enter every 5 minutes during script execution

Tags: bash, powershell, script

I have a scheduled task running every morning that takes a bit to run (about an hour). During the execution of the script, I notice that the progress bar for it will stall randomly until I focus the window and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. When I do, the progress continues where it left off and continues working until it either finishes or needs another <kbd>enter</kbd> press.

I wrote the script myself and can't figure out why it would stall, so I think my best course of action is to simulate an <kbd>enter</kbd> press every X amount of time to keep the script going if I'm not around to press it myself.

I haven't been able to find resources that could solve my problem, I was hoping someone could give me advice on how to accomplish this? My powershell script is basically as follows:

```
cd {{file path for running node script}}
yarn run start
```

Comment: Is this a PowerShell script run by `powershell.exe`? Is the scheduled task running under a user account?

Comment: It's run via task scheduler, I launch `powershell.exe` then feed in the file path to the `.ps1` file that contains the script for changing directory and running yarn

Comment: I feel this is an XY issue as you are trying to fix it in a manner that could lead to some security concerns. I would suggest sharing your script so we can help identify the root cause (obviously removing any personal details from the script.). If you are adamant with going with the approach you have personally suggested look into powershell sendkeys: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/perform-keystroke-in-powershell/#:~:text=the%20running%20application.-,Use%20the%20SendKeys%20Method%20to%20Perform%20Keystrokes%20Inside%20PowerShell,can%20send%20keystrokes%20to%20it.

Comment: You mean the actual node script? It's a large multi-file script that has way too much context to post here unfortunately. If you mean the powershell script, it's posted in its entirety above (excluding file paths and script input params).

The actual hang up is during the execution of a function from a node package but I can't see anywhere that it's waiting for user input. In fact, there's no requested user input anywhere in the script.

I'll look into sendkeys but is there a way to have that execute on a timer during the execution of the rest of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is by running your script, then running a second script that does the keypresses by focusing the window and sending an enter keypress to the open window running the yarn command. Kind of looks likes this. Not tested but conceptually-

**Script1.ps1  (your script)**

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "YarnScript"
cd {{file path for running node script}}
yarn run start
```

**Script2.ps1**  (focus running powershell window and press enter every 5 mins)

```
Start-Process "C:\temp01\script1.ps1"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
while (1) {$wshell.AppActivate('YarnScript'); $wshell.SendKeys('~'); Start-Sleep -seconds 300}
```

The first script (your script) should have a line added to set the Window title. I have chosen the name "YarnScript" here. This will be used in the second script to "Focus" the window that your script is running in and send keystrokes.

The second script is the one that you will add to task scheduler. This script calls your YarnScript and runs it. Once it is running, it infinitely focuses the window the YarnScript is in and sends the Enter (~) keystroke every 300 seconds.

I did not know how long to make the loop, so I just made it infinte and you can customize the length of time that the keystrokes keep getting sent for.

Comment: Awesome, this looks very doable and should solve it! I'll keep you posted on how this goes and if I run into any issues. Thank you so much!